# Action of vector field on Smooth Function

Tags: differential-geometry, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $F$ be a $C^\infty$ function from a $n$ dimensional manifold $M$ to a Hilbert space $H$. Let $X$ be a vector field defined on $M$. How can one define the action of $X$ on $F$?

Comment: The same way as if $H$ is $\mathbb R^N$.

Comment: For (smooth functions) $v: \Bbb{R^N\to R^N}$ and $f:\Bbb{R^N\to R}$ let $(D_v f)(p) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(p+hv(p))-f(p)}{h}$. Let $\phi$ bi-smooth $\Bbb{R^N\to R^N}$, what should be the value of $v_\phi(\phi^{-1}(p))$ to obtain $(D_{v_\phi} (f\circ \phi))(\phi^{-1}(p))=(D_v f)(p)$ for all $f$

Comment: What do you mean by $v_\phi$?

Comment: Oh, I see it should be $v_\phi(\phi^{-1}(p))=D\phi^{-1}(p)v(p)$

Comment: We want $v_\phi(p)$ to be the vector $w$ such that $\phi$ sends $\phi^{-1}(p)+hw$ to $p+hv(p)+O(h^2)$, thus $\phi^{-1}$ sends $p+hv(p)$ to $\phi^{-1}(p)+hw+O(h^2)$, thus $v_\phi(p) = w=(D_{v(p)}\phi^{-1})(p)$, this way our definition of the action of the vector field is chart independent. Equivalently as Eric suggested, send the vector to a parametrized curve with that vector as its tangent, and look at $(f\circ \gamma)'(0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way that vector fields act on functions is by taking derivatives in the direction of the vector field at each point.  One way to say this is that $XF:M\to H$ is the function defined by $(XF)(p)=(F\circ \gamma)'(0)$ where $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M$ is some smooth curve with $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=X(p)$.